# How to mount this image?

Tags: 12.04, mount

I'm trying to mount an image but I get some error:

```
$ sudo mount -o loop matlab2011a_64.iso /cdrom/ 
[sudo] password for dev: 
mount: warning: /cdrom/ seems to be mounted read-only.
```

I'm not sure that I should mount it the cdrom or some other destination. Can you tell me how I should mount the image?

Comment: generally mount user stuff in /media

Comment: I would suggest mounting it on `/mnt` instead of `/cdrom`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already have a cdrom, you should not mount another image as "cdrom". You have 2 possibilites:

- unmount your /cdrom (with `sudo umount /cdrom`). I would not recommend it. If you want to restore your old cdrom, you have to remember the path in /dev.
- make a new directory (preferrably in /media, but this is not necessary): `sudo mkdir -p /media/anyNameEvenCdrom` and after this `sudo mount -o loop matlab2011a_64.iso /media/anyNameEvenCdrom`